# Adding files to .gitignore doesn't remove them from "untracked files"?

Tags: git-svn

I recently started using git-svn, and tried to tell Git to ignore any files that the Subversion repo ignores (mostly binaries and object files), by running "git svn show-ignore >> .gitignore"

Then I ran git status, and saw that many of those files that are now on my .gitignore list, are still showing up under "untracked files". Why? What do I need to do to fix this?

Or am I going about this the wrong way? I just want to be able to run "git add ." without it adding in all that junk to the commit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already imported those files in the Git repo, they won't be ignored until you `git rm --cached` them.

You need to remove those file from the Git index (hence the `--cached` option), before seeing the `.gitignore` working.